# Any attribute (dropdown) should be chosen first on configurable product detail page in magento 2

Tags: attributes, themes, magento2, dropdown, configurable-product

**Current Scenario:**

1. First dropdown is enabled & have all options.
2. Second drop down is disabled. Plus it has no options. Once the first drop down is chosen, second dropdown options appear after this.

Please see screenshot.

[image: Screenshot for configurable product detail page]

I want both dropdowns should be enabled on page load. And user should be able to choose any of these first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for any third party module is installed which is doing this ?

Comment: Yes, some third party modules are installed. But I can't see any ajax request in Network console. Can you suggest something please.

Comment: Magento by default does not provides this scenario, so check for third party module which is responsible for this and try to disable it.